# Why does Falcon 9 launch with Crew Dragon solar panels facing down?

Tags: launch, crewed-spaceflight, falcon-9, dragon-v2, solar-panel

I noticed in video of the first crewed mission in August that Falcon 9 pitches down with the Dragon solar panels facing down.

I'd been expecting the solar panels to be facing up, because sun.

Does anyone know why the solar panels face down during launch? Is it to spare them the brunt of aerodynamic drag forces? Do they rotate the crew dragon after separation to ensure the solar panels face the sun?

Comment: Can you add a link to the video and mention the time at which this happens? It's a lot easier to answer when there's an actual example of what is being described. *Thanks!*

Comment: I don't know if the particulars for Dragon are published, but in general we refer to these as "pointing constraints."  The non-helpful non-answer here would be to say that other constraints are more important than the solar panel pointing during that phase of flight.